# Can I automatically disable certain pylint warnings if there is a hashbang in the script?

Tags: python, pylint

I often find myself disabling pylint from running in my editor while writing one-file executable Python scripts. I find that certain warnings which are useful in general are mostly noise in these types of scripts. For example, in these small scripts I'll often just declare variables in the global name space, and I'll ignore warnings about invalid constant names. Of course I could sprinkle a bunch disable comments, but I find this to be just as much noise as the warnings themselves. Consequently, when editing these small scripts, I tend to just disable pylint altogether. What would be ideal is if I could configure pylint to automatically disable certain warnings based on the contents of the file. For example, if there is a Python hashbang at the top of the file, then I don't want to see the invalid constant warnings. I've looked into various ways of disabling warnings and just found either global disables in the pylintrc or local disables via comments. Is it possible to selectively disable certain warnings automatically (i.e. without peppering the script with tons of disable comments)? To be clear, I don't want to disable *all* warnings just because this is a small executable script with a hashbang - just the few that I find to be less helpful when writing this kind of Python code.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `#pylint: disable-all` to the top of the file it will disable all warnings for the file. I couldn't find anything about disabling it with just a hashbang, however this will stop you from peppering your script with tons of comments. [Here is the reference for this.](https://docs.pylint.org/faq.html#how-can-i-tell-pylint-to-never-check-a-given-module)

Comment: The only problem with this is that it does exactly what it sounds like - it disables everything. What I want is to selectively disable only certain warnings. I admit this may not be possible, but then that is why I am asking :D

Comment: Ah my bad. You can list all of the warnings you want disabled at the top? `#pylint: disable=wildcard-import, method-hidden, ....`

Comment: I've done a bit more searching, and I think you may be right about just listing the disabled warnings at the top. Annoying, but doable.